# OTA plist app install from within Phonegap app for iPad

Tags: ipad, cordova, childbrowser

I am trying to initiate an OTA app install from within a Phonegap iPad app. I have tried this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/test.plist";
window.open("itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=" + url, "_blank");
```

This works in iOS 5 but **NOT iOS 6**.

I have also tried using the ChildBrowser plugin to point to a page with a link to the OTA app install, but that doesn't work either (if I visit the web page directly from within the native iPad browser, it works fine).

Does anyone know how I can initiate an OTA app install from within the Phonegap iPad app? (Must work in iOS 5 and iOS 6).

*I am trying to implement an auto-update feature within an ad hoc iPad app (not through the App Store). So when the app detects that there is a new update, it will prompt the user to install the new update and that's where I need this functionality.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. So as it turns out. The simulator for iOS 6 does not understand this url `itms-services://?action=download-manifest` and therefore was not working.

Everything worked fine after testing on a physical iPad running iOS 6.